# Is the root of a number defined as a single number or a collection of numbers?

Tags: definition, roots

I always had trouble understanding one thing about roots:

Imagine that we want to find the solutions for the following equation:

$$x^2 = 4$$

It's easy to see that the solutions are $2$ and $-2$.

But then I thought, what if we use the square root on both sides? We'd get:

$$\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt 4 \iff x = 2$$

So, does this mean that $\sqrt 4 = 2, - 2$ ? Does this mean that $\sqrt 4$ has two distincs values?

---

So, this question I had is just some contextualization and is what motivated this question.

Latter, in real analysis I actually learned that:

$$\sqrt{x^2} = 4 \iff |x| = \sqrt 4 \iff x = 2 \vee x = -2$$

and that's where the $-2$ comes from. So $\sqrt {4}:= 2$ and the $-2$ comes from the absolute value.

But then I considered the same question with the third power:

$$x^3 = 8$$

We can take the root on both sides and get:

$$\sqrt[3] x = \sqrt [3] 8 \iff x = 2$$

This time, $\sqrt[3]{x^3} = x$ and there are no absolute values. So it seems that this equation has only one solution, but we know that $-1 - i \sqrt 3$ and $-1 + i \sqrt 3$ are indeed solutions.

So where do those solutions come from? Does that mean that $\sqrt [3] 8 = 2$, $-1 - i \sqrt 3$ and $-1 + i \sqrt 3$?

It'd make sense that $\sqrt [3] 8$ is defined as only being $2$ and then the other solutions come from somewhere else. Is that the case? How do we define $\sqrt [n] a$? Is it only one number that we use to solve and find the other solutions to those kinds of equations? or is itself defined as the set of solutions for the equation $x^n = a$?

I recall, in highschool learning the following formula:

$$\sqrt [n] {r e^{i \phi}} = r^{1 / n} e^{i \frac{\phi + 2k \pi}{n}}, \ \ \forall k \in \{1,...,n\}$$

And wouldn't that imply that the root of a number is a collection of numbers instead of just one number?

Comment: It is a universally accepted convention that $\sqrt x$ stands for the positive square root of $x$ when $x>0$. There is no such convention for $x^{1/n}$ in general and $x^{1/n}$ can be any number $y$ such that $y^{n}=x$.

Comment: So $x^{1/n}$ is any number from the set of solutions for $y^n = x$, but not the set itself, as in it's not all of them ate the same time? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: It is best not to use $x^{1/n}$ except in the case $n=2$ and $x\geq 0$. Always use the term ' an $n-th$ root of $x$'.